# Style background-color property not being updated when the observable is changed

Tags: knockout.js, styles, background-color, observable

I am having some trouble figuring out why my background-color style in my template doesnt get updated when the checkbox is checked.

In my div tag I have:

```
data-bind="style: {"backgroundColor": isChecked == true ? "#00796B" : "#999"}"
```

Which I want to change the background color of my div tag when the checkbox is checked or unchecked. Right now the background color doesnt change but it seems my checks for the input tag work as intended.

```js
function checkboxViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.isChecked = ko.observable(params.isChecked || false);
    self.isDisabled = ko.observable(params.isDisabled || false);
}

ko.components.register('material-checkbox', {
    viewModel: checkboxViewModel,
    template:
      '<div class="checkbox" data-bind="style: {"backgroundColor": isChecked == true ? "#00796B" : "#999"}>' +
      '<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" data-bind="css: {disabled: isDisabled}, checked: isChecked, disabled: isDisabled" />' +
      '<label for="checkbox"></label>' +
      '</div>'
});

ko.applyBindings();
```

```css
.checkbox{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #999;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;

  input{
    visibility: hidden;

    &:checked + label{
      background-color: #00796B;

      &:before{
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }

  input.disabled{
    &:checked + label{
      background-color: #999;

      &:before{
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }

  label{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: inherit;

    &:before{
      content: "";
      width: 12px;
      height: 6px;
      border: 2px solid white;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
      top: 2px;
      left: 1px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="checkbox.less" rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.3/less.min.js"></script>

<material-checkbox params:"isChecked: false, isDisabled: false"></material-checkbox>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-debug.js"></script>
<script src="checkbox.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several typos and small syntax issues, most notably:

- The `isChecked == true` should invoke `isChecked` as a function because it's an observable. If you want to use an observable in a complex expression you have to do `isChecked()`. Only in simpler scenarios, where you just bind to the observable directly, you can omit the parentheses (e.g. with `checked: isChecked`).
- The quotes inside your template are messed up;

If you fix those the `backgroundColor` binding will work just fine:

```js
function checkboxViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.isChecked = ko.observable(params.isChecked || false);
}

ko.components.register('material-checkbox', {
  viewModel: checkboxViewModel,
  template:
    '<div class="checkbox" data-bind="style: {\'backgroundColor\': isChecked() == true ? \'#00796B\' : \'#999\'}">' +
    '<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked" />' +
    '</div>'
});

ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.3/less.min.js"></script>

<material-checkbox params:"isChecked: false, isDisabled: false"></material-checkbox>
```

Comment: This fixed it thank you so much! I do have one misunderstanding left. i know you have to invoke the variable as a function when it is an observable but why dont you have to for the input tag? Why doesnt data-bind="checked: isChecked" have to be invoked as a function

Comment: @user2367327 That's because Knockout will do that *for you*, under the hood. When binding to just the observable itself, it "knows" to invoke it as a function. This is especially importang for two-way bindings, where updates from view model to the DOM will invoke it as is, and updates from the DOM (e.g. user clicks) to the view model invoke `isChecked` with the new value.